# Calculate percentage In Django Database Query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to calculate the total cost of all the services with taxes in the bill using a single query. I don't understand where I am going wrong.

MODELS:

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)


class BillService(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    bill = models.ForeignKey(Bill, related_name='billservices', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Service(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, related_name='services', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    short_code = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class ServiceTax(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="servicetaxes")
    tax = models.ForeignKey(Tax, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Tax(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, related_name='taxes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tax = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)], default=0)
```

MY QUERY TO GET A SINGLE VALUE, THAT IS TOTAL COST OF THE BILL

```
    value = bill.billservices.all()
                .annotate(sum_of_taxed_percentages=Subquery(
                        Service.objects.filter(billservice=OuterRef('id'))
                        .annotate(total_tax_value=Subquery(
                            ServiceTax.objects.filter(service=OuterRef('id'))
                            .values('tax')
                            .annotate(total_tax=Sum('tax__tax', output_field=FloatField()))
                            .values('total_tax')
                        )).annotate(taxed_value=F('price') + ((F('price') * F('total_tax_value')) / 100))
                       .values('taxed_value')
                       .annotate(total_services_taxed_value=Sum('taxed_value', output_field=FloatField()))
                       .values('total_services_taxed_value')
             ))

             print(value[0].sum_of_taxed_percentages)
```

ERROR:

```
'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'select_format'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trial and errors, I found the solution.

```
   service_tax = ServiceTax.objects.filter(service=OuterRef('service')) \
                .values('tax__tax')
   value = bill.billservices.all() \
                .annotate(service_taxes=SQSum(service_tax)) \
                .annotate(service_price=F('service__price')) \
                .aggregate(total=Sum(F('service_price') + ((F('service_price') * F('service_taxes')) / 100),
                                     output_field=FloatField()))
   print(value)



class SQSum(Subquery):
    template = "(SELECT SUM(tax) FROM (%(subquery)s) _sum)"
    output_field = models.FloatField()
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is where you're calculating the percentage:

```
taxed_value=F('price') + ((F('price') * F('total_tax_value')) / 100)
```

on this trench:

```
((F('price') * F('total_tax_value')) / 100
```

i think you need to change some parentheses:

```
(F('price') * (F('total_tax_value') / 100))
```

because you first need to divide the percentage you have stored to 100 and then you multiply that by the price of the object to then sum to the current value of it:

```
taxed_value=F('price') + (F('price') * (F('total_tax_value') / 100))
```

Check if it works, i'm not sure, it seems that is a simple formula problem...

Comment: the problem seems to be outside of this code, it seems somewhere on your code you are trying to query a value on a table cell called 'select_format' which seems that doesn't exist